# unique integer/long hash key generation over strings for faster compairson

Tags: algorithm, string, hash, comparison

I'm curious how others have solved this problem, and what problems might lurk behind the naive solution:

I have a system which processes stock market data.  There are tens of thousands of symbols, with associated prices/sizes, flowing into the system at the rate of several thousand every millisecond.

One of the basic operations that needs to happen on every tick is string comparison to see if the incoming matches the symbol we are interested in.  At such high frequency, optimization of these string comparisons can make a measurable difference in the performance of the whole system.

I am thinking of generating a hash of the symbol string, and storing it with the record.  For subsequent comparison, the system should use this hash (being an int or a long, the comparison should be a single operation, rather than iterating through each character of the string until a mismatch is found).

Let's ignore the cost of generating the hash itself (which, in reality, may actually be prohibitive).  The only problem I can see is that with a large number of unique symbols, a hash collision (two separate symbols generate the same hash) would be devastating.  Is there a hashing algorithm which guarantees that strings which match certain constraints (such as limit on the number of characters) are unique?

EDIT: I'll write this code in Java.  Not sure of the (collision) quality of hashCode or the speed with which it is calculated.

Comment: Have you considered using one or more of the following general purpose hash functions:  hashhttp://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html

Comment: For those who want to click the link http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe hash functions aren't the best approach here. If you're receiving a ticker symbol (and not the hash of the ticker symbol) you're going to have to compute the hash for it every single time it comes through. If its a hashing algorithm with no collisions, you'll need to look at every character of the symbol anyway. So you might as well directly compare the characters.

I suggest building a Trie data structure of all the tickers you're interested in. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Traverse the tree for each symbol and if you reach the end of the ticker without finding a match, then its not an interesting ticker.

With hashing, you'll have to do this traversal anyway in the set of all hash values of the interesting tickers.

Comment: Good point about the cost of calculating the hash in the first place.  Although I decided to ignore it for this question, it is a real concern...but one which I can answer by running tests.  I do expect that I will store every incoming tick into a Map keyed by the symbol (so the most recent data will overwrite the old data).  Elsewhere in my program, the Map will be used for looking up as often as new ticks come in.  Since each time a bid or an offer comes in, it'll need to be combined with last sale price to create an aggregate tick.  That's why precalculating hashes might be worth it.

Comment: Along the same lines as rethinking the hashcode solution, another way is simply to increment an atomic long every times a new symbol comes in and put it in a map.  Obviously check the map before incrementing the counter.  Right now I have no idea what the cpu cycle cost of this will be, but at least I can test it.  Simpler solution and keeps me from worrying about hashcode collisions.  Either way, this optimization will be hidden away from the public API

Answer (score 5):

Common cryptographic hash functions like SHA-1 outputs 20 bytes (160 bit). How long are your stock symbols? If we're talking about [ticker symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol) like "WMT" (Walmart), "KO" (Coca-Cola), etc, then they seem to be only a couple of bytes long -- thus it should be faster to compare them directly instead of dealing with a 20 byte hash. You mention hash collisions -- I wouldn't worry about them, especially not when the inputs are much smaller than the hash output.

You might be able to cast the bytes into an `int` or `long` depending on the programming language and platform and then do the comparison between these "numbers" in one CPU instruction. (I don't know if modern compilers can compare a bunch of bytes equally fast with a call to `memcmp`?)

Comment: Seconded.  Not sure if it makes sense in Java, because of all the shifting & or-ing required, but you can pack a lot of information into a 64-bit long and on modern hardware the actual comparison should only take a cycle or two.  Don't forget Java strings are Unicode, so you'll probably want to strip off the high-order byte first.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using a [Perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), I think it fits your requirements

Answer (score 2):

If you use String.intern() or your own String pooling you can then use == rather than .equals() - I've done this in similar performance critical code and it has made a big difference. The default String already has a hashCode() which works fairly effectively.

I've just realised it wasn't a Java question, but the same applies. Yes, hashing and then using identity checking can save time. The java hashing algorithm uses:

> ```
>      s[0] * 31^(n-1) + s[1] * 31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```

Comment: Not a Java question but my code will be in Java :)  I should have mentioned Java, which does include a hashCode function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving 4-letter ticker symbols, then each letter should be representable as a single byte. Pack all 4 together into a 32-bit int, and voila, you have your "hash". You can now compare this against the reference using a single machine instruction.

If you weren't using Java, that is.

I really wouldn't suggest using Java for anything speed-critical, especially not thousands of string comparisons per millisecond.

edit: If you wanted to use 64-bit code, you could pack up to 8 letters per long int and then compare in 1 instruction.

Comment: +1. But I doubt you need 64-bit code for stock ticker symbols -- each letter can be represented in 5 bits, meaning 6 letters sit comfortably in a 32-bit word. Packing like this is fast -- just a subtraction and bit shift per character.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the hash by treating the string as a Base-27 number (assuming the symbols contain only letters). This would generate the uniqueness you're looking for. For example:

> (no letter) = 0, A = 1, B = 2, ... Z = 26
>
> AA = (1 x 27<sup>1</sup>) + (1 x 27<sup>0</sup>) = 28
>
> AAA = (1 x 27<sup>2</sup>) + (1 x
>   27<sup>1</sup>) + (1 x 27<sup>0</sup>) = 757
>
> BBB = (2 x 27<sup>2</sup>) + (2 x
>   27<sup>1</sup>) + (2 x 27<sup>0</sup>) = 1514
>
> GOOG = (7 x 27<sup>3</sup>) + (15 x 27<sup>2</sup>) 
>   + (15 x 27<sup>1</sup>) + (7 x 27<sup>0</sup>) = 149128

This will work fine up to 6 characters in a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a fast hash function that has good discrimination power.
For each string, compute the associated hash function and store it with the string.
Then for a comparison, code:
     if  (Hash(s1)==Hash(s2)
          && s1==s2)
     then { ...   }
The actual string compare won't occur unless the hashes match, which in practice
is only when the strings match.

Some folks will tell you to implement a perfect hash.  You can only do
that when the set of strings you want to hash has bounded size, usually
only 10-1000.  You can't do that for an arbitrarily big vocabulary of strings. 
Since you can't do that, you actually have to compare the strings to determine equality.

Cryptographic hashes have great discrimination power but aren't designed
to be fast.   What is generally very fast and has good discrimination
power are CRC functions, and most langauges have easily found libraries
that compute these quickly (using a table lookup technique on bytes).
We use CRC-32 and it is very effective for this (basically 1 chance in 2^32 that a hash collision will occur, when the strings
don't match).   You can use CRC-64, but the additional discrimination power
it provides won't really add any real functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Any decent hash function handles collisions well. Basically, if the hash results in a hit for which multiple answers exist, there's a linked list of potential solutions in that bucket, and of necessity, things slow down in finding the correct answer (if one exists).

But don't write your own hash function, use one that is out there.

Oh, and generating the hash should be done only once, I would think. Because you have a lookup table of things you are tracking, and the hash table should only have to change when you add a new "interesting" thing to scan for.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Better comments than my own were thrown on (and earlier), making mine redundant at best.

Answer (score 0):

I second the above suggestion of a Trie structure as the best approach for this case. Computationally equivalent to a perfect hash, but conceptually much prettier. This is presuming your symbols are bounded in length.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, on the last high-data-volume project I was on, we found filtering, aggregating and pre-classifying data using some heavily-tuned C code was key.  All our feeds went into this pre-processor and it took care of the simple data cleansing before passing the bulk of the data to our Java-based system for processing.  Basically the pre-processor did just what you're asking: identifying records of interest, verifying they were complete and removing dups and empties.  During peak times the pre-processor could eliminate up to 20% of the 8M or so records we'd get per hour (probably not quite the volume I imagine you get from stock market feeds).  Our original Java version was lucky to get half that (but it was "elegant", at least!)

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth. I solved this problem specific to CMS (NYSE) and CQS (NASDAQ) symbology. Symbol roots will be at most 6 characters long and will be uppercase. My requirements were as follows:

- Data would arrive for unknown symbol
- Upon receiving data compute a hash value to be used for comparison
- Compute the value once, store the value in a map for future comparison
- Value comparisons will be equality
- Value comparisons will be against a range.

For Example If data for GOOG arrives it will need to be processed and distributed to processes in the symbol  range [F-HAA]. ( F <= GOOG <= HAA ) . I used a range class that has a low value (F) and a high value (HAA). My Hash function concept is similar to packing the characters into bytes but for logging,network, and endian purposes I chose unsigned long long as my storage type. Prior to calling this function the symbols are padded with an '@' character. (IBM@@@)

```
unsigned long long SymbolToVal(std::string& str)
{
 size_t maxlen = 6; // Symbology constraint
 if (str.length() != maxlen) return 0;
 unsigned long long val;
 unsigned long long retval=0;
 int expon = maxlen*2; // ASCII val range (65-90)
 double factor = std::pow(10.0,expon);
 expon-=2;
 for (size_t i = 0; i < maxlen; i++)
 {
    val = (unsigned long long)factor * str[i];
    retval += val;
    factor = (unsigned long long) std::pow(10.0,expon);
    expon-=2;
  }
  return retval;
 }
```

A brute force method would be to compute all possible symbols sort them properly and assign them an integer then store them in a map. May be overkill if incoming data only consists of a small portion of the total domain (which is the normal case).